# Java Language Recognizer

Tags: java

I was given the assignment to "implement and test a language “recognizer” object, provided to you through a Java interface defined at the end of this document. A language recognizer accepts strings of characters and determines whether or not they are in the language."

The language is as follows:

L = {a*b} union {ab*}, or restated in English, L is the set of all strings of either (1) zero or more as (a*) followed by a b, or (2) an a followed by zero or more bs (b*).

I've made some progress, but I'm stuck.

Here's the interface:

```
/** The Recognizer interface provides a recognizer for the
* language L below.
*
* Let Sigma = {a,b} = the input character set.
*
* Let L = {ab*} union {a*b} be the language (set of
* legal strings) recognized by this recognizer.
*
* Let S = s1s2...sn be the string of n characters already
* input by this recognizer.
*
* Recognizer constructor must ensure: S' = < >
*/
interface Recognizer {
/**
* require: c in Sigma
*
* ensure: S' = S ^ c
*
* param c
*/
public void nextChar(char c);
/**
* Checks if input string S is in language L.
*
* return (S in L)
*/
public boolean isIn();
/**
* ensure: S' = < >
*/
public void reset();
}
```

Here's my structure:

```
import java.util.*;

public class LanguageVector implements Recognizer {

    int element = 0;
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;

    Vector<Character> v = new Vector<Character>();

    public void nextChar(char c) {
            v.add(c);
        }

    public boolean isIn(){
            boolean isTrue = true;
            for(int i=0;i<v.size();i++) {
                if (v.size() == 1){
                    if (v.firstElement() == 'a' || v.firstElement() =='b'){
                        isTrue = true;
                        }
                    else
                        isTrue = false;
                }
                else if (v.firstElement() == 'a'){
                        if (v.lastElement() == 'a')
                            isTrue = false;
                        else if (v.lastElement() == 'b')
                            while (v.elementAt(element)== 'a' ){
                                a++;
                                element++;
                                System.out.println(element);
                            }
                            while (v.elementAt(element)== 'b'){
                                b++;
                                element++;
                                System.out.println(element);
                                }
                            if (v.elementAt(element)!= 'b'){
                                isTrue = false;
                            }
                            else if (a > 1 && b > 1){
                                isTrue = false;
                            }
                            else
                                isTrue = true;
                    }
                else if (v.firstElement() == 'b'){
                        isTrue = false;
                        }
                else
                    isTrue = false;
            }
            return isTrue;
            }


    public void reset(){
                v.clear();
            }

}
```

And here's my testing class:

```
import java.util.*;

public class LanguageTester {
    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Recognizer r = new LanguageVector();

        r.nextChar('a');

        r.nextChar('a');

        r.nextChar('a');

        r.nextChar('b');

        if (r.isIn())
            System.out.println("string is in L");
        else
            System.out.println("string is not in L");
        System.out.println("End of test");
        r.reset();
    }
}
```

When I run, I get the following output:

```
1
2
3
Exception in thread "main" 4
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4 >= 4
    at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Unknown Source)
    at LanguageVector.isIn(LanguageVector.java:34)
    at LanguageTester.main(LanguageTester.java:18)
```

Why is this happening?

Also, how can I use user input, turn it into a vector, and use that within this structure now?

Forgive me if this question is too lengthy, I wasn't sure how to narrow it down without leaving important details out. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### When it occurs?

Out of bounds exception is occurred when you try to access an array with index that exceeded its length. maximum index of a java array is (length -1)
for example:

```
String [] stringArray = new String[10];
stringArray[10]
// the code above will produce an out of bounds exception, because the it bigger than length -1, which is 10 - 1 = 9.
```

If you don't know the size or length of an array, you can know it from `stringArray.length`.

### How to handle it?

You should make sure that your program doesn't access an array with index bigger than length - 1.
example:

```
for(int i=0;i<stringArray.lenght;i++) {
    //write your code here
}
```

the above code will guarantee that `stringArray` will never be accessed beyond its maximum index.

### Your Case

In your case, `4 >= 4` itself says you are trying to access 5th element i.e. `elementAt(4)` however size of your Vector of 4.

Array is based on 0 index i.e. if your length is 4 you will have data at as Vector[0], Vector[1], Vector[2], Vector[3].
Also read [this](http://www.roseindia.net/java/java-exception/index-out-bound-exception.shtml) for more info...

Comment: Thank you, that made sense. I tried incorporating that for loop intro my structure, and I think I got it working. However, it didn't fix the error... My updated code/output are in the original post

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the `isIn()` method. You're not checking whether the element variable is still below `v.size()`. You just continue incrementing it so the next time that the application accesses `v.elementAt(element);` the variable element is bigger than the size of v, so it's an ArrayOutofBounds exception.

Comment: I realize now that it's because of the element becoming larger (or equal to) v.size, but I can't find a workaround to fix this.